# Value of Select Option in Django's Views.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using select tag in template along with a link having 'submit' type inside a form tag. When I select an option from the dropdown and click on the button, it goes to the next page but I am unable to get the value of the options selected. Its showing AttributeError 'Manager' object has no attribute 'month'. Here is my code:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'results' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
<select name="mahina" id="month">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="jan">January</option>
            <option value="feb">February</option>
</select>
<a href="{% url 'results' %}" type="submit">Search</a>
</form>
```

Here is my views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Results


def allresults(request):
    results = Results.objects
    if request.method == "GET":
        month = results.month
        year = results.year
        return render(request, 'results/allresults.html', {'results': results}
```

Comment: are you trying to access the values from drop-down in the POST in your views.py?

Comment: I have changed it to GET

Comment: ok, so in your views.py what are you trying to do here, `results = Results.objects` , if you are trying to query the model, check out the docs here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects) , the query you have written seems incomplete.

Comment: I want to get the value of the option selected inside the select tag

Comment: if you want to get the value of the selected option in the view then change your logic inside view see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to get the form values in the views, you must do like `form_val = request.GET.get('field_name', <default_value>)` , so to add a few lines in the code

```
def allresults(request):
    # this will get the value of the selected item, print this to know more
    mahina = request.GET.get('mahina', None)

    #Just writing the below query field month randomly, since the models isn't posted
    results = Results.objects.filter(month=mahina)

    # We don't need to give GET since by default it is a get request

    # Since there are multiple objects returned, you must iterate over them to access the fields
    for r in results:
        month = r.month
        year = r.year

    return render(request, 'results/allresults.html', {'results': results}
```

Comment: glad to hear that, do accept this answer so that if someone referrs this answer, they can be sure it is right

Comment: I tried this and it also worked:

    ````def allresults(request):
    results = Results.objects.all()
    mon = request.POST['mahina']
    yea = int(request.POST['saal'])
    pdf_url = {}
    ti = []
    da = []

    for i in results:
        m = i.month
        y = i.year
        f = i.file
        u = f.url
        t = i.title
        d = i.date
````